# Исключить все десятизначные числа из названий

Tags: python, python-3.x

В таблице имеются данные разных компаний, в столбик, где пишется название компании, иногда попадает `ИНН`, состоящий из `10` цифр (`1000000000`-`9999999999`), как можно отобрать такие названия? Просто исключить все числа нельзя, т.к. в названиях компании может попадаться число.

Comment: Лучше всего регулярное выражение используйте.

Comment: Они не подходят, т.к. могут попадаться другие цифры, которые должны быть в строке
Решил проблему путем подсчета цифр, если больше или равно 10, то удаляется последнее слово, которое как раз-таки и есть ИНН, а если меньше 10 цифр, то остается как есть

Comment: Чего это не подходит-то, регулярка как раз и может находить все последовательности из 10 цифр...

Comment: Видимо стоит изучить их подробнее, спасибо за информацию, буду учиться дальше!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярное выражение: `[0-9]{10}` - ровно десять знаков, входящих в диапазон от 0 до 9. Или `\d{10}`, что то же самое (`\d` означает любую цифру). Но будет находить и последовательности из 10 цифр внутри более длинных последовательностей из цифр, т.к. там внутри тоже есть 10 цифр подряд. Поэтому, если встречаются такие длинные "числа", и их нужно оставить, то регулярку нужно чуток подработать.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно посчитать количество цифр в строке, если количество больше или равно 10, то такая строка подходит под отбор и проходит дальнейшее форматирование  и удаляются 10 цифр в конце, а иначе остается, как есть

```
num = [int(i) for i in i if i.isdigit()]
g = len(num)
if g >= 10:
    print(" ".join(i.split()[:-1]))
else:
    print(i)
```